# how to compile @angular2 modules and dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have just started a new project using Angular2 and Typescript from the [Angular material get started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) page.
Everything was working fine until I introduced a service using Http from '@angular/http';
When ng serve is running, I got a runtime error saying Http is not a NgModule
and when I stop and rerun ng serve I got a compiling error :
ERROR in Http is not an NgModule
webpack: Failed to compile.

After some digging around I tried adding index.ts at the root folder and exported the Http class as follow :

```
export {Http} from '@angular/http';
```

I then then executed the command :

```
tsc -p .
```

But with no effect.
I also tried

```
ng build --aot
```

Which gives pretty much same error :
*ERROR in Unexpected value 'Http in C:/..../myproject/node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in C:/..../myproject/src/app/app.module.ts'
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:...\myproject\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts*

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You dont need to export Http at all. Just import HttpModule in AppModule like this:

import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

make sure you have @angular/http in your package.json. And if you are implementing some service, make sure it is Injectable and registered in AppModule under "providers" array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to import HttpModule in app.module.ts and use HttpModule under Imports, For example see the below code

```
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

  @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule
    ],
 declarations: [],
 providers: [],
bootstrap: []
    })
```

And in Service you need to import the Http Module

```
import { Http, Response, Headers} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class Service {
        Your Code......
}
```

Comment: I had all those instructions in place! the only difference which was the problem is the fact I imported Http within app.module.ts even if it wasn't part of the imports array. thanks